# How to build a list from Postfix maillog

Tags: email, logging

I want to build a list from maillog, `maillog.x` containing something like Date, Sender's email, Recipient's Email and subject of the message filtering output emails and output domain.

I've read about importing from spreadsheet program a csv file. The issue is I have to add field separators in log file. I couldn't figure out how to customize that.
How can I do that, the list and the separator?

This is an example of sending mail log

```
Jun 11 15:24:58 host postfix/cleanup[19060]: F41C660D98A0: warning: header Subject: TESTING SUBJECT from unknown[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]; from=sender@sender.com> to=recipient@recipient.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.1.91]>
Jun 11 15:25:01 host postfix/smtp[19062]: F41C660D98A0: to=<me@me.com>, relay=mx-rl.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25, delay=3.4, delays=0.66/0.01/0.86/1.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 <538E30D9000A1DD8> Mail accepted)
```

The list would contain the subject, from, and to, filtering by `to = ...@recipient.com`

Answer (score 2):

Try aillog-hashnize.pl from https://gist.github.com/xtetsuji/1446584
It is a perl script to parse maillog file and produce output file as CSV. Then import CSV into Excel and apply filter as you wish (@recipient.com).

> perl maillog-hashnize.pl -y 2016 maillog-20160124 > maillog.csv

Answer (score 1):

You could try opening it with [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/),  It asks you for the separator when you open a CSV file.   For that to work you would have to rename the file as `maillog.csv` so that LibreOffice knows that it is a CSV file.

I suspect that won't work well.   Instead, I would get things in the right format with Unix command line tools first.

Use `grep` to only show the lines with a recipient that you are interested in:

```
grep -E 'to=[a-z]+\@recipient\.com'
```

Use `sed` to remove the parts of the line you don't need.   Sed uses `s/find/replace/g` syntax.  I would use four find and replaces like this:

```
sed -r 's/.*Subject: //g;s/ from .* from=/\t/g;s/ to=/\t/g;s/ proto=.*//g'
```

Putting it all together would be this command line:

```
cat maillog.x | grep -E 'to=[a-z]+\@recipient\.com' | sed -r 's/.*Subject: //g;s/ from .* from=/\t/g;s/ to=/\t/g;s/ proto=.*//g' > /tmp/maillist.csv
```

Then */tmp/maillist.csv* would contain:

```
TESTING SUBJECT sender@sender.com>  recipient@recipient.com>
```

Comment: 1) I forgot to add the date of the transaction

2) Output file contains extra data like:
SUBJECT <user@sender.com> <user@recipient.com>
Jun 12 15:23:00 host postfix/smtp[13074]: 1997C60D9943: <user@recipient.com>, relay=mx4.recipient.com[yyy.yyy.yyy]:25, delay=8.4, delays=6.4/0.01/0.54/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250  <000401cf866b$528f2810$f7ad7830$sender.com> Queued mail for delivery)

3) Separator is Tab?

Comment: I get two lines: Subject-Sender-Recipient and the other starting with the date I commented above. I also need the date I guess I can get with something like substring(1,16)